# AngularJS JSON Editor toggle editable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently, I'm using [ng-jsoneditor](https://github.com/angular-tools/ng-jsoneditor).

I'm trying to toggle the state from editable to read-only.

To set the readonly property I have to specify the `onEditable` property of the `options` property. For instance:

```
 $scope.obj = {
            data: json, 
            options: {
                mode: 'tree',
                onEditable: function(){return false;}
            }
  };
```

I am able to get the `changeOptions` property to toggle the `mode` property, however I cannot get the `onEditable` property to toggle. I want the user to have the capability to edit the json while in the `'code'` mode. This is what I tried:

```
    $scope.changeOptions = function () {
        $scope.obj.options.mode = $scope.obj.options.mode == 'tree' ? 'code' : 'tree';
        $scope.obj.options.onEditable = $scope.obj.options.onEditable == function(){return false;} ?  function(){return true;} :  function(){return false;};
    };
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/sd3at5ek/298/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

Didn't quite get your question at first, my bad.

In your example what you were doing wrong was checking a variable for a  function definition which is `onEditable()`, which quite does not work.

So what I did was check if mode is `tree` or `code` then assign a function to `onEditable` option of `ng-jsoneditor`.

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sd3at5ek/302/).

**PS:** I did clean some code as well.

Comment: Oh yea? Did you test the demo? Did you notice the demo allows you to edit both in tree mode and code mode? I want to disable the capabilities of editing while in tree mode. The use case is basically, while in tree mode make the editor read only and while in code mode allow the user to modify the json.

Comment: @PhiL please check now.